# How to access inherited members of derived class when instantiated in a different project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inheritance

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 (Community Edition) that contains multiple projects, as follows:

1. Project 1:

   In Project 1 I have defined a class that derives from the DbContext class of Entity Framework. It's defined along the lines of the following:

   ```
   public class MyContext : DbContext
   {
      public DbSet<EntityClass> EntitySet {get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Project 2:

   I also have a Console Application project inside of my solution that references Project 1.

   When I create an instance of MyContext inside of Project 2 I cannot access the members inherited by MyContext from the DbContext class without adding a reference to Entity Framework and a using directive to the System.Data.Entity namespace.

Is there anyway to be able to access the members my derived context class have inherited from DbContext in Project 2 without:

a. Adding a reference to Entity Framework and writing a using directive for the System.Data.Entity namespace in a code file in Project 2; Or

b. Manually exposing each public member of DbContext in my derived context class?

Comment: @Leonel: My apologies, I've edited the code displayed on this question to be consistent with the code in the Solution. The class is defined public in Project 1.

Comment: Since the property type, `DbSet<T>`, is already part of the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, you’re pretty much out of luck here.

Comment: @poke: Ok, thanks I hadn't thought through the implications of the DBSet<T>. I'm going to have to "layer" something else in, eg. a "repository", so i can just return either a single or collection of T..

Comment: You absolutely can add another layer, often referred to as repository pattern, which hides the entity framework stuff. Then, if you use dependency injection and only depend on interfaces, you could avoid having to add the entity framework to your dependent project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, That is not possible. Your project1 reference is depend upon other reference. You need to add all dependent reference under project2.

Comment: Ok thanks, looks like maybe if I if build another layer, I could break the project dependencies.